# What is the range of depth sensor of Azure Kinect?

Tags: azurekinect

How closest to sensor object can be? I would like to know if i can have it like 15cm close to sensor, do I get relevant data? I cannot find these information on microsoft site. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Depth data tends to drop off under 30cm in NFOV and 20cm in WFOV. As for how it looks this close, this is my hand at these distances:

[19cm WFOV binned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGSpu.png)

[28cm NFOV unbinned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt8Vx.png)

Answer (score 1):

WFOV modes are spec'd to give you the best performance in a shorter distance. The distance spec is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/hardware-specification#depth-camera-supported-operating-modes.